What is the earliest known children's rag doll?
What is the earliest known children's rag doll?
Several sites reference this doll found at Oxyrhynchus in Egypt, dated to between the 1st and 5th centuries CE, as having been found in a child's grave, but the website of the British Museum - where the doll is now located - doesn't confirm this:

Perhaps this doll is the answer to the question. I would agree that if it actually was found in a child's grave it can confidently be called a child's rag doll, and I know of no earlier children's rag dolls.
But perhaps a later doll is an answer to the question.
I suspect that rag dolls are not as ancient as some claim.
A children's rag doll is defined as a doll for children, representing a human being, stuffed with scraps of fabric, papyrus, or other fairly soft or squidgy stuff, rather than being made from, say, wood or stone.

Would you like me to transfer it to History.SE? This is technically a question about the origin of material culture, and thus perfectly at home there, too.

Hi @cmw - Since nobody has posted an answer here, could you transfer it now? Hopefully it will get some answers in the other place. Many thanks!
